# jQueryUI Draggable: Constrain draggability to a single axis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

When dragging an object, the user can drag in the x and y axes. I want to constrain the draggability to only the x-axis. How should I go about doing this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out the [axis](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-axis) option:

> "Constrains dragging to either the horizontal (x) or vertical (y) axis. Possible values: 'x', 'y'."

Examples:

```
// Initialize a draggable with the axis option specified.
$( ".selector" ).draggable({ axis: 'x' });

// Get the axis option, after initialization.
var axis = $('.selector').draggable('option', 'axis');
// Set the axis option, after initialization.
$('.selector').draggable('option', 'axis', 'x');
```